# How to get the relative position of a tkinter canvas after it got scaled and dragged around?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

The canvas c is the basis of a kind of CAD modelling software I'm working on. The methods for transforming it work (bound to mouse button 2).
In another function I want to add/edit items on the canvas so I need the new relative position to the canvas.

Context:

That should be (0,0) in the end:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85zPN.png)

The following is a minimal reproducible example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1000x500")

c = tk.Canvas(root, width=1000, height=1000,
              bg="white")
scalingFactorIndex = 0

def callback(event):
    print(c.canvasx(event.x),c.canvasy(event.y))
    print(c.canvasx())

def create_grid(event=None):
    w = c.winfo_reqwidth()  # Get current width of canvas
    h = c.winfo_reqheight()  # Get current height of canvas
    c.delete('grid_line')  # Will only remove the grid_line

    # Creates all vertical lines at intevals of 25
    for i in range(0, w, 25):
        c.create_line([(i, 0), (i, h)], tag='grid_line')

    # Creates all horizontal lines at intevals of 25
    for i in range(0, h, 25):
        c.create_line([(0, i), (w, i)], tag='grid_line')


def move_start(event):
    c.scan_mark(event.x, event.y)


def move_move(event):
    c.scan_dragto(event.x, event.y, gain=1)


def zoomer(event):
    if (event.delta > 0):
        c.scale("all", c.canvasx(event.x), c.canvasy(event.y), 1.1, 1.1)

    elif (event.delta < 0):
        c.scale("all", c.canvasx(event.x), c.canvasy(event.y), 0.9, 0.9)




    scrollRegion = (c.bbox("all"))
    c.configure(scrollregion=((-150, -150, scrollRegion[2]*1.5, scrollRegion[3]*1.5)))

c.bind("<Configure>", create_grid)
c.bind("<ButtonPress-2>", move_start)
c.bind("<B2-Motion>", move_move)
c.bind("<MouseWheel>", zoomer)
c.bind("<Button-3>",callback)
c.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

Edit:
Through further experimentation and comments, I found out that it has only to do with the zoom function. The other problem could be solved with using canvasx(event.x). However, after zooming and moving, the coordinates are wrong again and get more wrong the longer you use it.

Comment: If you create a [mre] I'll show you.

Comment: Are you aware of the `canvasx` and `canvasy` methods of the canvas? Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @BryanOakley I think they want to have coordinates from the screen and is only needed if the item is shown. But without a [mre] and a proper explanation it is much of a guessing and too much code to write for them, at least for my dedicated will to help.

Comment: I added a minimal reproducible example. I hope it helps. To clarify my end goal more: I want to add an object to the model (on the grid) where the mouse pointer is. Therefore the mouse pointer and scaling need to be relative to the canvas (the grid)

Answer (score 0):

In a comment you wrote:

> To clarify my end goal more: I want to add an object to the model (on the grid) where the mouse pointer is.

To do that you need to pass the x/y coordinate from the event through the `canvasx` and `canvasy` methods.

For example, if you want to draw a circle under the mouse pointer when you press "o", you can do something like this:

```
...
def create_circle(event):
    x = event.widget.canvasx(event.x)
    y = event.widget.canvasy(event.y)
    event.widget.create_oval(x-10, y-10, x+10, y+10, fill="red")
...
c.bind("o", create_circle)
c.focus_set()
...
```

If you want the drawn object to be at the same scale, you'll have to apply the scaling factor to the coordinates yourself. The above code will give you the correct starting point under the mouse.